# If I update the DOM with new elements/html, do I have to unbind/rebind event handlers?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Say I have a page with a drop down list, and it currently has 10 elements.

My page has a websocket connection, that receives some html which I then replace the entire section which had the drop down list.

```
<div id="ddlArea">
   <select name="cars" id="cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

So I get some html from a websocket connection, and replace the drop down list area:

```
$("#ddlArea").html(updatedDropDownListHtml);
```

Now if I had a click event that was bound to the cars drop down, should it still work?

```
$("#cars").click(...);
```

I know jquery used to have this concept of `live` where it would rebind itself or something.

Just trying to understand why I have to do this, or if I don't.

Would it be a better approach to just render the drop down list from a JSON collection somehow, and if I get a new JSON collection of new elements, then do a remove and then re-add the new items to the drop down list?

Comment: Can't you just hide the dropdown?

Comment: jQuery `.live()` has been deprecated for many many years, but that idea is basically the right answer: *event delegation*. If you handle events at the `document` level, and then choose handlers based on a selector that identifies the event target, your handlers will work no matter how many times your DOM is edited, so long as you're consistent in using class names or whatever to control functionality associated with elements.

Comment: why is it deprecated?  did browsers change how this works?